# Installing PHP 5.4 instead of 5.5 on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: php

Any one please suggest commands to install PHP 5.4 instead of PHP 5.5 that comes default with Ubuntu server 14.04

For some compatibility issues i want to install PHP 5.4 not 5.5. I have a fresh server with nothing installed as of now.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure to look at the "5.4" part of the accepted answer there

Comment: Yes, found it thanx man